# How do you keep the keyboard visible after you click the Send key

Tags: iphone, keyboard, visible

In my iPhone APP I have a view with a textfield and a button (to remove the view).

My main goal is to have the keyboard always visible.

I made a "Send" button visible on the keyboard and am able to capture when the send button is pressed.

Hoever, when you press the send button the keyboard is removed.  What I would like is for the keyboard to remain visible and the text from the textfield to be cleared and be textfield to have focus ready for some more typing.

Adding:

```
[textChat becomeFirstResponder];
```

in the Did End On Exit event does not work.  I am not sure if I should be using one of the other events.

There are a ton of samples and tutorials on how to remove the keyboard, not one on how to keep it.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you are talking about. Is this on an Android? PC? Ipad? et cetera

Comment: Sorry, this is Objective-C using Xcode for the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyboard is removed when it stops being the first responder. There is a delegate method you can implement, `textFieldShouldEndEditing:`, which is called when the text field is asked to resign from being first responder. You could implement this and have it return NO after you do whatever you want to do with the data in the text field (send it somewhere), clear the field, etc.